# function to look for the substring in the String and get some information after finding the substring

Tags: mysql

I have a table called organization which has a column `treeId`. Tree id is used to manage wich organization is allowed to watch the profile of the other sub organizations. The values of the treeId in the table could be

```
1|2|44|23|56|12|
1|2|44|23|56|5|
1|2|42|21|52|
```

Now I want to show all organization name which comes after the searched organizationId also if I would look for 44 --> I want to show the organization name of `56, 12, 5`  also all number after 23 without repetition. Is there a function in mysql to manage it?

**organization table**

```
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lastWrite              | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status                 | varchar(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name                   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city                   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email                  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| homepage               | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mobile                 | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nameAffix              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notice                 | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone                  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| poBox                  | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| street                 | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| zipCode                | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fax                    | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| providerId             | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| treeId                 | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| showCopyright          | bit(1)       | NO   |     | b'1'    |                |
| type                   | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| trackingUserInterface  | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country                | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| iconStrategy           | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notificationInterval   | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| refreshInterval        | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dateFormat             | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dateTimeFormat         | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| locale                 | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timeFormat             | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timeZone               | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| defaultOrganization    | bit(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| longDateFormat         | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| showAllStatus          | bit(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| coordinateFormat       | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| params                 | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mapAndReportWidth      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reverseGeocoderGroupId | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| memo                   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| redirectAfterLogin     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any good methods for looping through data like that. You should store multiple values in separate rows, not a delimited string.

Comment: This is why using concatenated IDs in a table instead of a resolution of many to many in an intersection table is almost universally a bad idea.  You will have to parse them out in your code and then issue queries against them.  SQL does a fine job concatenating but has no split function other than nested substring kinds of things.  This happens, but never should.  Caused by either laziness or ignorance.